# How to set name above a part of a matrix?

Tags: support, mathjax

[image]

I want to create the matrix that is shown in the image, and my code is:

```
    \begin{equation}
     B=
     \begin{pmatrix}
     \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
      0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
      & R &  &  & A & \\
      \hline
      & 0 &  &  & 0 &
      \end{array}
     \end{pmatrix}
     \end{equation}
```

It works, and makes the matrix, but I don't know how to create the labels above or next to the blocks.

Comment: You may have more success with this at [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is effectively not possible with MathJax right now since it does not yet have implemented colspan and rowspan. The way right now is to manually hack the correct placement. If you move the braces inside, you could simply create a 2x2 matrix for B and use overparen etc in the relevant cell.

Comment: Posting this question at tex.stackexchange.com might result in several different ways this can be done. Some of those may require a level of TeX sophistication beyond what you're willing to work with, or have more bells and whistles than what is reasonable for the context in which you're working, but some may be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, though it is a hack.

```
B=\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
0\,\cdots\, 0 & \smash{\overbrace{0\,\cdots\, 0\strut}^p}\\
R & A\\
\hline
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)\!\!\raise .7em{\bigg\}\vcenter{\scriptstyle p}}
\Rule{0em}{3.4em}{0em}
```

which produces:

$$
B=\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
0\,\cdots\, 0 & \smash{\overbrace{0\,\cdots\, 0\strut}^p}\\
R & A\\
\hline
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)\!\!\raise.7em{\bigg\}\vcenter{\scriptstyle p}}
\Rule{0em}{3.4em}{0em}
$$

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for proving me wrong ;-)